# A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, set, listboxitem, .net

In my WPF application, I've written one double click event for listbox item.When I double clicked on existing entry of the listbox, that entry submitted successfully.

This is code:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Submit clicked Entry
        try
        {
            ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
            Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)item.Content;

            if (!entryToPost.isSynced)
            {
                //Check if something is selected in selectedProjectItem For that item
                if (entryToPost.ProjectNameBinding == "Select Project")
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Project for the Entry");
                else
                    Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(entryToPost);
            }
            else
            {
                //Already synced.. Make a noise or something
                MessageBox.Show("Already Synced;TODO Play a Sound Instead");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
     }
```

But when I select projectname from project combobox, it shows me an exception- TargetInvocationException.
Inner Exceptions are: System.InvalidCastException , System.FormatException.

I think, problem is inside setters of the projectNamebinding. so how should I proceed?

Code for projectNameBinding is:

```
public class HarvestTimeSheetEntry
{
private int _projectid { get; set; }

public string ProjectNameBinding
    {
        set 
        {

                this._projectid = Int32.Parse(value);

        }
        get
        {
            if (entrySource == source.harvest)
                return Globals._globalController.harvestManager.getProjectEntriesThroughId(this._projectid)._name;
            else if (entrySource == source.googlecalendar)
                return "Select Project";
            else if (entrySource == source.processInfo)
                return "Select Project";
            else
                return "Whaaa?";
        }
}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint in the setter, if its hit step through till you find your culprit

Comment: I also have timer for recording. so after 20 secs of starting timer, one new entry generated in listbox. and then in that entry when I select project from comboBox, it shows me an exception.

Comment: Why `Convert.ToInt32(this._projectid)`? It is already `int`.

Comment: @Clemens that was mistake.I corrected it.But still showing same exception

Comment: From a quick glance, your problem might be that you seem to be trying to cast a ListBox to a ListBoxItem in your DoubleClick handler.

Comment: @Chris You are right.When I double click on existing entry of listBox, it works fine. But after recording(i.e 20 secs) when new entry generated, then while selecting project name from combobox, it shows me exception.

Comment: The first thing you should do is fill your empty catch block with some error message output. And I agree with Chris, you can't write `ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;` as sender seems to be a `ListBox`.

Comment: @Clemens I added message in my catch block. If I try in above way-   Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)sender.Content;

Comment: It shows me an error and says I can't cast listboxItem to that class object. But when cast listBox to listBoxItem, it works.